# UPDATE based on if value exist in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, sql-update, case

I have two tables

Table A

```
Number
111       
222       
333       
444
```

Table B

```
Number    Another
111       AAA
222       BBB
666       CCC
777       DDD
```

What I am would like to do, is apply an UPDATE statement conditional on whether the "Number" value in Table B exist in Table A. So the table would end up looking something like this.

```
Number    Another
111       ZZZ
222       ZZZ
666       CCC
777       DDD
```

I know I need to use an UPDATE query and probably some kind of JOIN, but I am not sure on the syntax.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. You need to update using a join like this:

```
update t2
set t2.Another = 'ZZZ'
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.Number = t2.Number
```

Comment: All good answers, but this is the methods that worked best for my scenario. Thanks

Comment: I have a similar situation on my hands. Would it be possible to use this but with a WHERE clause at the end of it, to filter out t2 entries I don't want to update?

Answer (score 6):

You can use directly SELECT FROM table1 and update into table2 :

```
UPDATE table2 SET Another = 'ZZZ' 
FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.Number = table2.Number
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `exists` also.

**Query**

```
update t1
set t1.[Another] = 'ZZZ'
from [TableB] t1
where exists(
    select 1 from [TableA] t2
    where t1.[Number] = t2.[Number]
);
```